# Relation of Wick theorems

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, operators, wick-theorem, thermal-field-theory

In the context of quantum stat mech it is common to use Wick's theorem to refer to the factorisation
$$
\langle f_1 f_2 f_3 \cdots f_N\rangle = \sum_{\text{pairings}\, \pi} (\pm 1)^{|\pi|} \langle f_{\pi_1} f_{\pi_2} \rangle \langle f_{\pi_3} f_{\pi_4} \rangle \cdots \langle f_{\pi_{N-1}} f_{\pi_N} \rangle
$$
where $\pm 1 = -1 (1)$ for fermions (bosons), the $f_i$ may be creation or annihilation operators, and $\langle \cdots \rangle = \mathrm{tr}[\cdots \mathrm{e}^{- \beta H}]$ for some bilinear hamiltonian $H = \sum_{ij} h_{ij} f_i f_j$. (Please correct this statement if it is mistaken---I have been looking for it in the literature without immediate success).

How is this statement precisely related to the canonical statement of Wick's theorem, which is most often introduced as a relation between the normal ordered and time ordered operator products
$$
\begin{align}
T[f_1 f_2 f_3 f_4 f_5 f_6\ldots] &= \mathopen{:} f_1 f_2 f_3 f_4 f_5 f_6\ldots \mathclose{:} \\
&\quad + \sum_\text{singles} \mathopen{:} f_1^\bullet f_2^\bullet T[f_3 f_4 f_5 f_6 \ldots] \mathclose{:} \\
&\quad + \sum_\text{doubles} \mathopen{:} f_1^\bullet f_2^{\bullet\bullet} f_3^{\bullet\bullet} f_4^\bullet T[f_5 f_6 \ldots ]\mathclose{:} \\
&\quad + \ldots
\end{align}
$$
In particular, this statement seems of most obvious utility only when considering vacuum expectation values which kill all of the uncontracted terms, which is not true for finite temperature expectation values. (Maybe a different notion of "contracted" or "normal order" is at play?)